# Javascript merge some properties of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, find

I have 2 arrays with objects inside them:

```
names = [
    {
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "name": "D"
    },
    {
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "name": "A"
    }
]


 sections = [
    {
        "id": 3638,
        "name": "B",
        "type": "PANEL",
        "parentSectionId": 3635,
        "order": 1,
        "page": "595"
    },
    {
        "id": 3658,
        "name": "C",
        "type": "PANEL",
        "parentSectionId": 3635,
        "order": 2,
        "page": "595"
    },
    {
        "id": 3659,
        "name": "D",
        "type": "PANEL",
        "parentSectionId": 3635,
        "order": 3,
        "page": "595"
    },
    {
        "id": 3636,
        "name": "A",
        "type": "PANEL",
        "parentSectionId": 3635,
        "order": 4,
        "page": "595"
    },
    {
        "id": 3661,
        "name": "B",
        "type": "PANEL",
        "parentSectionId": 3635,
        "order": 5,
        "page": "595"
    }
]
```

I need to merge some propoerties of sections array inside names array.
The properties to be merged are: id and order.

The problem is with id. Because there is one duplicate name: 'B' the id is being duplicated.

I tried many things, but they fail because puts same **ID 3638** on both duplicate names: 'B'.

Here is the wrong output i get:

```
section {id: 3638, name: 'B', order: 1, size: undefined}
section {id: 3658, name: 'C', order: 2, size: undefined}
section {id: 3659, name: 'D', order: 3, size: undefined}
section {id: 3638, name: 'B', order: 4, size: undefined}
section {id: 3636, name: 'A', order: 5, size: undefined}
```

And here my last code attempt:

```
 const childrens = names.map((c, i) => ({
        ...c,
        id: this.sections.find((s) => s.name === c.name).id,
        order: i + 1,
      }));
```

**THIS IS THE CORRECT AND FINAL OUTPUT I NEED:**

```
    [
        {
            "name": "B",
            "order": 1,
            "id": 3638
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "order": 2,
            "id": 3658
        },
        {
            "name": "D",
            "order": 3,
            "id": 3659
        },
{
            "name": "B",
            "order": 4,
            "id": 3661
        },
        {
            "name": "A",
            "order": 5,
            "id": 3636
        }
    ]
```

As you can see the second B is in 4th place with order: 4 and id: 3661.

Comment: because your `names` array have two time `"name": "B"`, so first you have to remove duplicate from `names` array.

Comment: I need that duplicated key. The name is the same but the order is diferent.
It's a TAB system.
I have tabs B C D B A

Comment: add your final output you want.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i added the final output i need.

Comment: `names` and `sections` array also must be same sequence data for getting index value, but if you use some extra function like `find

Comment: They are not in the same sequence and i cannot have them in the same sequence.
I need to work only with names array that cames in the correct sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were going in the right direction

For full merge, use :

```
let children = names.map((name, index) => { 
  return({
    order: index +1,
    name: name.name,
    ...sections[index]
  })
})
```

For partial merge :

```
let children = names.map((name, index) => { 
  return({
    name: name.name,
    order: index+1,
    id: sections[index].id
  })
})
```

I think you don't need the .find() and only use indexes

Comment: It not working because i need to maintain the order that comes in names array. Second name B has order 4. It is in the fourth place. I need to inject ID in names array.

Comment: Edited to suit your requierements

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work.
{
    "name": {
        "name": "B"
    },
    "order": 1
}

Comment: Edited, you just have to name.name to extract name property out of name of names.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i added the final output i need.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, this code will preserve the order for duplicate `names` (it's a raw version for a proof of concept)

```
 merged = []
 visited = []
  
  for (let i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<sections.length; j++) {
      if ((names[i].name === sections[j].name) && !visited.find(e => e === sections[j].id) ) {
        const obj = {...names[i]}
        obj['order'] = sections[j].order
        obj['id'] = sections[j].id
        merged.push(obj)
        visited.push(sections[j].id)
        //continue
        break
      }
    }
  }

console.log(merged)
```

output:

```
[
  { name: 'B', order: 1, id: 3638 },
  { name: 'C', order: 2, id: 3658 },
  { name: 'D', order: 3, id: 3659 },
  { name: 'B', order: 5, id: 3661 },
  { name: 'A', order: 4, id: 3636 }
]
```

Comment: Almost there. The order of the second B must be 4.

Comment: @AndréCastro I think this output is correct. `B` mapped with correct order id `5` . How you are expecting it to be `4` ?

Comment: Because it has to maintain the order that comes in the names array. I didnt post it, my fault, but i injected an order prop in each name, and the second name B is order 4. Sorry :(

Comment: You can see the order prop where i wroted: "Here is the final output"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i added the final output i need.

Comment: I made some changes in your code and now it is working as i expected.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: then just replace `continue` with `break` and you'll get the desired output. The keyword `break` will jump out of the inner loop soon the properties are merged and will move to the "next" item of the `names` array. See the updates